# Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method in react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, gradle, module

```
Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method .onShouldStartLoadWithRequest(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 12): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, AppRegistry, RCTEventEmitter.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
```

I have already try clean gradle and clean project and again rebuild project in android studio. This error occur only in android device.